# Have table row scrollable

Tags: html, css

Currently facing some problems with the layout I want to accomplish.

How can I divide my page in such a way that the header row gets the height it needs ( for it's content ) and all the rest is given to the images row? A bit like auto, 100% if that is possible? For testing I've given it a fixed height.

The text in the header row should be bottom alligned vertically but somehow this is not working?

And lastly, how can I get the images row scrollable in such a way that the header row stays fixed? So not sticky for the header, because then the header will also partially scroll. The complete content of the header should stay fixed and only the images content should scroll on Y value. ( so no horizontal scroll )

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.table {
display:table;
width:100%;
}

.row {
display:table-row;    
  }

.row.header {
height:80px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row.images {
overflow: scroll;
}
  
.column {
display: table-cell;
width: 50%      
}

.column.left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.column.right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
      <div class="column left">Portfolio</div>
      <div class="column right">Artist</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row images">
      <div class="grid">
      <div class='grid__col-sizer'></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpg"></div>
      </div>        
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `height: fit-content;` To make the height of the div fit the height of the elements it has

code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.table {
display:table;
width:100%;
}

.row {
display:table-row;    
  }

.row.header {
/* here you can replace fixed hight with : fit-height */
height:fit-height;
display: flex;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row.images {
overflow: scroll;
}
  
.column {
display: table-cell;
width: 50%      
}

.column.left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.column.right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
      <div class="column left">Portfolio</div>
      <div class="column right">Artist</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row images">
      <div class="grid">
      <div class='grid__col-sizer'></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg"></div>
      <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpg"></div>
      </div>        
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That does indeed give it the needed height, but the row will still scroll along with the rest... any way to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problems, using CSS grid. [The complete codepen is available here: https://codepen.io/depechie/pen/jOBGrRP](https://codepen.io/depechie/pen/jOBGrRP)

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

.panel {
    display: grid;
/*  grid-template-rows: var(--bar-height) 1fr; */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

.panel-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tab-item.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.tab-item.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```